# Two definitions of Bruhat order on $S_n$

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups, coxeter-groups

Let $s_i = (i, i+1)$ be the $n-1$ transpositions that generate $S_n$.  The (strong) Bruhat order says that $u \le v$ if for some reduced word $w$ composed of $s_i$ representing $v$, there is a (not necessarily contiguous) subword of $w$ that represents $u$.

My question is, is it true that if $u\le v$ under the definition above, then for EVERY reduced word $w$ representing $v$, we can find a subword representing $u$?  I have seen this stated as a definition too but do not know why they are equivalent.

Generalizations to Coxeter groups are welcome, but I prefer an answer that just focuses on $S_n$.

Comment: The is true. You may find  more details in Bjorner-Brenti, chapter 2. As for $S_n$, note that there is a criteria for Bruhat order in $S_n$ that is completely independent of reduced words/subwords, and only focuses on some quantities derived from the cycle representation (also discussed in Bjorner-Brenti). Thus, such a statement as above automatically follows for $S_n$. If you have any doubts from that section, you may ask.